# Application of Alternating series test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n^n}{n!e^n}$ convergent?

This is inconclusive by ratio test. I tried to use root test, but ended up with $\displaystyle\frac{n}{e(n!)^\frac{1}{n}}$. So, now stuck. Is there any way of applying alternating series test here?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation#An_alternative_derivation) we get

$$\frac{(-1)^n n^n}{n!e^n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^{3/2}}\right)$$

- the series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$ is convergent by the Leibniz theorem
- the series $\sum \mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^{3/2}}\right)$ is also convergent by comparison with a Riemann series hence the given series is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

The Stirling approximation gives

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n!e^n\over n^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}=1$$

Then our $n^{th}$ term is comparable with ${1\over \sqrt{2\pi n}}$ in size, so the series converges by alternating series.